# Getting Variables From Java constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm new to Java programming, sorry if this is a dumb question.

I find it hard to word this question properly, but I have an assignment to create a aircraft class that can make aircraft land, takeoff etc. And need to test it using Testclass. When the new object are entered it automatically assigns a unique ID to the aircraft in the constructor.

I can do this using a instance method fine as it has a return value which is returned to to Testclass. The question wants me to do this in the constructor itself, however, the constructor never returns anything. So the variable never gets sent to the Testclass. I clearly am not understanding OOP properly. Even when I try to just use a `getter` method to get the ID created in the constructor it gives me the initialized variable before the the constructor has worked on this. This is the code I have so far and its completely wrong I know but if someone could point me in the right direction or tell me how to word this question better it would be a massive help.

```
// I need to enter 3 aircraft into the system in the testclass

public class Aircraft {

  private int aircraftID;
  private static int lastID;
  private String airportcode;
  private int ID = 100;

  private int count;



  public Aircraft(int a, int b, int c){
    // Constructor


     // Assign ID
     this.ID = a;
     lastID = ID;
     ID++;

     this.ID =b;
     lastID = ID;
     ID++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't return anything from a Constructor. So the question is flawed or you have misunderstood the question. A constructor doesn't have a return type and is used when you do `Aircraft aircraft = new Aircraft(1, 2, 3);` so I suppose it returns you an instance of `Aircraft` if you want to look at it that way

Comment: Your frustration is evident, and understandable; we've all been there. When you say you've been told to test it using Testclass, are you talking about building unit tests?

Comment: I think I did word it wrong and it is not a Testclass but a unit test. When new aircraft(objects) are entered they will be assigned a unique ID. So when I use Aircraft ac = new Aircraft(); it's meant to do the above then I think. Yeah my frustration is more with me not knowing how/what to google/ask, my lecturer said OOP is a hard concept to get a hold of but once you have it you have it.

Comment: Sorry for editing and re-editing my answer; I was rushing. \*facepalm\*

Answer (score 1):

OK, you want to create an Aircraft that has an automatically-assigned unique identifier, and can take off and land. That implies you need a field for tracking the identifier, a field for tracking whether it's in the air (or not), and methods for the take off and land operations. You also need a static field for generating the unique identifiers. (Note that this implementation isn't thread safe.)

```
private class Aircraft {

    private static int staticId = 0;
    private int uniqueId = 0;
    private boolean onGround = true; // Aircraft start on the ground in this implementation

    public Aircraft(){
        this.uniqueId = staticId; // putting this line first makes uniqueId zero-indexed in effect
        staticId++;
    }

    public void land(){
        onGround = true;
    }

    public void takeoff(){
        onGround = false;
    }

    public boolean isFlying(){
        return !onGround; // If it's not on the ground, it's flying
    }

    public int getUniqueId(){
        return uniqueId;
    }
}
```

Unit tests checks all of the methods and expected functionality of the class in question:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import Aircraft;

class Testclass {

    private final Aircraft aircraft = new Aircraft();

    @Test
    public void hasId(){
        aircraft.getUniqueId() >= 0;
    }

    @Test
    public void canLand(){
        assertTrue(aircraft.land());
    }

    @Test
    public void canTakeOff(){
        assertTrue(aircraft.takeOff());
    }

    @Test
    public void checkFlightOperationsAreTrackedCorrectly(){
        aircraft.land();
        assertFalse(aircraft.isFlying());
        aircraft.takeOff();
        assertTrue(aircraft.isFlying());
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly thank you so much for this. You answered another question I needed an answer to with this code. I really appreciate this.  I think I'm starting to understand more now, when I create the Aircraft that's basically similar to a data type and I need to describe that data type in the code, whereas with the constructor I was just coding it like a normal method. Many thanks Bill!

Comment: You’re very welcome! I’m happy to help. Note you should really add documentation to the Aircraft class (test classes should be self-documenting.) And feel free to accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out a constructor does not return anything (the simplified version is that with `new` it returns an object instance). I am kinda guessing at what you are trying to acomplish, but I'll have a go anyways. It seems to me that you are trying to cram the construction of 3 objects into one constructor - which is why your constructor has 3 parameters. Also you are playing havoc with the IDs.

I have removed all the variables that I didnt quite understand, leaving only ID that increments with each instantiated `Aircraft`. The `@Override` is mainly just for show.

```
public class Aircraft {
    private int aircraftID;
    private static int lastID = 0;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Aircraft_" + this.aircraftID;
    }

    public Aircraft() {
        lastID++;
        this.aircraftID = lastID;
    }
}
```

I took the liberty and wrote the `TestClass` just to see if we have the same thing in mind. Again the `printAircraft()` method is for show.

```
public class TestClass {
    private List<Aircraft> aircrafts;
    public TestClass(){
        aircrafts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addAircraft(Aircraft a){
        aircrafts.add(a);
    }

    public void printAircraft(){
        Iterator<Aircraft> it = aircrafts.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and to test it, we create and instance of `TestClass` add 3 `Aircraft` instances and print out the contents

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass tc = new TestClass();
    tc.addAircraft(new Aircraft());
    tc.addAircraft(new Aircraft());
    tc.addAircraft(new Aircraft());
    tc.printAircraft();
}
```

This would be the case if you are to write the `TestClass`. If that is given, it would help to know what it looks like - maybe that would help us understand better.

Comment: Wow amazing, thank you so much. I do believe I worded it wrong in the question in the sense that I need to create a unit test rather than a testclass. But its great to go through someones code and understand whats going on so thank you!